# Conversion App On Webserver Keeps Timing Out

Tags: php, html

So, this is going to be a lot of explaining but i have a webserver set up through ubuntu, and i currently have a html form set up as:

```
    <form action="Converter.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="font-family: verdana" target="_blank">
        <input type="file" name="userfile" style="font-family: verdana">
        <input type="submit" style="font-family: verdana">
    </form>
```

This is meant to accept a user given text file through the form, rewrite the text inside of it and post it to a new tab for the user to either download or copy/paste. Currently the converter.php is set up as:

```
    <?php 
    $InputFile = $_FILES['userfile'];
    $Input = fread($InputFile, filesize("$InputFile"));

    $SearchVals = ["location /", " { add_header X-Redirect-By \"Yoast SEO Premium\"; return 301 ", "/; }", "; }"];
    $ReplaceVals = ["rewrite ^\/", "\\/?$ /", " permanent;", "/ permanent;"];

    $Input = str_replace($SearchVals, $ReplaceVals, $Input);
    $Input = str_replace("/https:", "https:", $Input);

    $Index = strpos($Input, "https:");
    $Endex = strpos($Input, ".com");
    $Str = substr($Input, $Index, $Endex - $Index + strlen($Endex) + 1);

    echo $Input;
    ?>
```

But when i submit the form it brings me to a new tab and proceeds to time out without giving me another error beside the time out.

Answer (score 1):

`fread()` according to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) requires a handle, and to do this you need to use `fopen()` (see the docs for examples). Since you're not opening the file, you can't read it, and `$Input` starts empty and ends empty.

When you echo out an empty string, nothing appears, so this is why you're getting a blank tab. As for it opening in another tab, that's how `target="_blank"` works, it opens in a new blank tab.

Along with this, usually if you go into whatever you're hosting your web server on, you can view a log of PHP errors. That usually helps let us know what's going wrong.